# Resolving "code is unreachable" in sorbet

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I maintain the pdf-reader ruby gem, and I'm experimenting with static type checking via sorbet.

I have a [particular source file](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/blob/4e70b32ca47f1e5ef0e90f29c6158936f4b6b755/lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb) that's currently `typed: false`, and I'd like to change it to `typed: true`. When I do so, sorbet complains about this state machine shaped method:

```
    def process_data(data)
      parser = build_parser(data)
      mode = :none
      instructions = []

      while token = parser.parse_token(CMAP_KEYWORDS)
        if token == "beginbfchar"
          mode = :char
        elsif token == "endbfchar"
          process_bfchar_instructions(instructions)
          instructions = []
          mode = :none
        elsif token == "beginbfrange"
          mode = :range
        elsif token == "endbfrange"
          process_bfrange_instructions(instructions)
          instructions = []
          mode = :none
        elsif mode == :char || mode == :range
          instructions << token
        end
      end
    end
```

I get this error:

```
$ srb  tc
./lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb:74: This code is unreachable https://srb.help/7006
    74 |        elsif mode == :char || mode == :range
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ./lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb:74: This condition was always falsy (T::Boolean)
    74 |        elsif mode == :char || mode == :range
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Got T::Boolean originating from:
    ./lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb:74:
    74 |        elsif mode == :char || mode == :range
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

./lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb:75: This code is unreachable https://srb.help/7006
    75 |          instructions << token
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ./lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb:74: This condition was always falsy (T::Boolean)
    74 |        elsif mode == :char || mode == :range
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Got T::Boolean originating from:
    ./lib/pdf/reader/cmap.rb:74:
    74 |        elsif mode == :char || mode == :range
```

I'm fairly confident that the code that sorbet believes in unreachable to definitely executing in production. This class wouldn't work if that was the case.

Presumably there's something about this code structure or the type annotations that makes sorbet believe that `mode` can never equal `:char` or `:range`. So far I haven't been able to work it out though. What am I missing?

Comment: You initially set `mode = :none` so sorbet probably concludes that it cannot equal `:char` because it doesn’t take the `while` loop into account.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is related to [this bug](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/820). I would mark `mode` as unsafe for now.

```
mode = T.unsafe(:none)
```

You can play with the code on [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%20%20%20%20def%20process_data%28data%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%20%3D%20T.unsafe%28%3Anone%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20instructions%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20token%20%3D%20random_method%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20token%20%3D%3D%20%22beginbfchar%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%20%3D%20%3Achar%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elsif%20token%20%3D%3D%20%22endbfchar%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%20%3D%20%3Anone%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elsif%20token%20%3D%3D%20%22beginbfrange%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%20%3D%20%3Arange%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elsif%20token%20%3D%3D%20%22endbfrange%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mode%20%3D%20%3Anone%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elsif%20mode%20%3D%3D%20%3Achar%20%7C%7C%20mode%20%3D%3D%20%3Arange%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instructions%20%3C%3C%20token%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20%20%20end)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I tried splitting the conditional with `||` into two `elsif` branches, but I still get the error. Looking at other open issues on GitHub though, [this one looks like it might be relevant](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/4174). Unfortunately I can't use the workaround because I don't want sorbet to be a runtime dependency of the gem